# System libraries in conda environment not seen by reticulate

Tags: python, r, conda, libstdc++, reticulate

I'm trying to get the R package `reticulate` working on a CentOS 7.8 system using RStudio Server v1.2.5042 with a custom environment created with `conda`.  When I initiate a Python job with `reticulate`, I get an error that some system libraries are not the correct versions, specifically, `libstdc++.so.6` and `libz.so.1`.

First off, I realize CentOS 7.8 is a bit old and some of the problem might be solved by upgrading the OS, but that's not an option in this case.

The `conda` environment does work and I can run the target Python script in a terminal window without any errors.  In RStudio using `reticulate`, the code is extremely simple at this point:

```
   library(reticulate)
   use_condaenv('test')
   py_run_file('test_script.py')
```

When the script is run, I get the following error:

`` ImportError: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /home/<user>/.conda/envs/test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/_lib/_uarray/_uarray.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so) ``

When I look into the `/usr/lib64` directory, I find `libstdc++.so`, but running `strings libstdc++.so | grep ^GLIBC | sort` shows me that it indeed does not support version `GLIBCXX 3.4.21`.  No surprises.  If I navigate to the `/home/<user>/.conda/envs/test/lib` directory, I find another copy of `libstdc++.so.6` and this one does support version `GLIBCXX 3.4.21`.  So, the correct version of the library is present in the correct `conda` environment directory, but for some reason RStudio and `reticulate` are not finding it.

I tried changing `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to have the `conda` environment directory listed first, but that does not work.  I found a lengthy discussion [here](https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/issues/292), which points out that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` isn't really a good fix unless it is set prior to the RStudio process initialization.  (And then goes on a tangent about which version of Python gets used.)  For my situation, there may be multiple `conda` environments to support and it isn't possible to know which will be active for any given session, and any given user my use different/multiple environments.  I would rather not try to harmonize all `conda` environments into one, big, uber-environment.

I've also verified that the Python version and other libraries are correctly set:

```
python:         /home/<user>/.conda/envs/test/bin/python
libpython:      /home/<user>/.conda/envs/test/lib/libpython3.8.so
pythonhome:     /home/<user>/.conda/envs/test:/home/<user>/.conda/envs/test
version:        3.8.5 (default, Aug  5 2020, 08:36:46)  [GCC 7.3.0]
numpy:          /home/<user>/.conda/envs/test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy
numpy_version:  1.19.1

NOTE: Python version was forced by use_python function
```

I have been able to get it running by resetting the links in `/usr/lib64` to point to the copy in the `conda` directory.  While this gets it working for this instance, I'm not sure I want to push a fix like this to production.  My guess is that if I link to the most inclusive version of the library across all `conda` environments, and that version fully supports all versions that the system level library supports, everything will be fine, but this feels like a hack, at best.

If anyone has found a good solution to this, I would appreciate to know the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After struggling with a similar issue for several days, and trying many of the suggested solutions on the web (mostly based on symlinks, LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable, or installing/upgrading/downgrading packages like libgcc), I finally found something that is only mentioned once here : https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/issues/338#issuecomment-415472406

The problem possibly seems to be a conflict when `R` is installed on the OS (with `apt-get r-base` for example) rather than with (Ana/Mini)conda.
In that case, it will try to load system libraries rather than conda environment ones.

So here is a possible solution to people still having this kind of issue, that worked for me :

1. (maybe optional) uninstall `R` on the local system : `apt-get remove r-base r-base-dev`
2. Activate conda environment : `conda activate my_R_env`
3. Install R within this environment : `conda install r r-essentials --channel conda-forge`
4. Install R packages like reticulate inside the same env : `conda install r-reticulate --channel conda-forge`

You can check that your Python packages installed within your conda environment are now properly loaded with `reticulate` :

- `R`
- `> library(reticulate)`
- `> repl_python()`
- `>>> import pandas` or any package that was causing the initial issue

*Note* : I still had some issues due to R loading base conda environment instead of activated one, but deactivating/reactivating environments or calling `use_condaenv('my_R_env')` seems to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have also been struggling with this issue although I am unable to uninstall/reinstall R as I am on a work system and don't have privileges for that.

What worked for me was abandoning the idea of using conda altogether and moving over to virtual environments instead, so consider that option if you're going round in circles.

Workflow:

1. In terminal: `python -m venv ~/.virtualenvs/myenv`
2. In R: `reticulate::use_virtualenv("myenv")`
3. In terminal: `source ~/.virtualenvs/myenv/bin/activate`
4. In terminal: `pip install matplotlib` or whatever packages you need
5. In python, either sourcing script from R studio or using `reticulate::repl_python()` to get the python prompt: `install matplotlib.pyplot as plt` or whatever was causing the issue

Hope that helps